# Getting duplicated requests - getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, node.js, asynchronous, react-redux, next.js13

I'm using "next": "13.4.0" with **Pages router**.

I have an application that uses a payment platform called **MercadoPago** and i'm making the checkout proccess through this platform. The backurl when the payment step finishes, it's pointing to one of my application pages, where i'm using **getServerSideProps** to register the resulting data of the payment platform in our **backend** and also feeding with this data our **frontend** to give feedback to the client.

The trouble comes because the **payment platform** has **two** ways of going back to the site. One it's automatic after 5 seconds, and the other it's manual clicking on "back to the site button"(i added an image for you to check) [payment plaform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/680g7.png). When the user clicks on "go back to the site" button, a redirection it's made but for some reason it's taking to long, so it reaches the automatic redirection that shoots after 5 seconds, so i'm receiveing **two requests almost at the same time** , so the logic inside **getServerSideProps** it's being called twice.

How can i avoid this behaviour or fix it? I add some code.

```
import { useCustomDispatch } from 'src/hooks/redux';
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';
import { ServerService } from 'src/services/ServerService';
import { ORDER_STATUS_ID } from 'src/utils/constants';
import { clearCart } from 'src/redux/slices/cart';
import { Checkout } from 'src/modules/checkout';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

export interface MercadoPagoFeedBack {
  id: string | string[] | null;
  payment: string | string[] | null;
  status: string | string[] | null;
  merchantOrder: string | string[] | null;
}

const FeedBack = ({ data }: { data: { orderStatus: number; orderId: string } }) => {
  const dispatch = useCustomDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    (ORDER_STATUS_ID.paid === data?.orderStatus ||
      ORDER_STATUS_ID.awaitingConfirmation === data?.orderStatus) &&
      dispatch(clearCart());
  }, [data?.orderStatus, dispatch]);

  const defaultStep =
    (ORDER_STATUS_ID.paid === data?.orderStatus && 4) ||
    (ORDER_STATUS_ID.awaitingConfirmation === data?.orderStatus && 5) ||
    (ORDER_STATUS_ID.notDefined === data.orderStatus && 2) ||
    (ORDER_STATUS_ID.active === data?.orderStatus && 2) ||
    5;

  return <Checkout defaultStep={defaultStep} receiptId={data?.orderId} />;
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const token = (await getToken({ req: context.req })) as {
    user: { accessToken: string; webUser: { id: number } };
  };

  try {
    let feedbackResponse: MercadoPagoFeedBack = {
      id: context.query.collection_id ?? null,
      payment: context.query.payment_id ?? null,
      status: context.query.status ?? null,
      merchantOrder: context.query.merchant_order_id ?? null
    };

    let data = {};

    if (Object.values(feedbackResponse).some(value => !value || value === 'null')) {
      return {
        props: {
          data: {
            orderStatus: ORDER_STATUS_ID.notDefined,
            orderId: context.query.collection_id
          }
        }
      };
    }

    const response = await ServerService.validateMpFeedback(
      feedbackResponse,
      token?.user?.accessToken
    );

    data = response.data?.error ? response.data : response;
    return {
      props: {
        data
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    return {
      props: {
        data: {
          orderStatus: ORDER_STATUS_ID.notDefined,
          orderId: context.query.collection_id
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

export default FeedBack;
```

I have tried identifying the request, and i notice it has a parameter that allows me to identify it, but if i return then frontend it's rendered with wrong information.

I also tried storing result of the request inside of my redux, so if that data it's stored then  don't make the request **ServerService.validateMpFeedback** , but the requests are almost at the same time so i don't get the results before the request it's called again.